# How to deploy oracle apex application on client machine

Tags: oracle

I have created oracle apex application in oracle apex 18.0. Now I want to put it online so that end user can access it. I have searched for solutions but it's all showing deploying the application in Oracle workspace only. Will it need to install all Oracle stuff in client machine too? Can't I upload it on the server and provide URL to the client?

Comment: APEX is a browser based app, so yes, the user should be able to run it via the correct URL.

Comment: Then how to deploy it

Comment: APEX applications are *always* deployed in an Oracle APEX workspace, there is no other option. You can deploy APEX on any Oracle Database. Where is your Oracle database? If it's currently running on your own standalone PC or laptop you'll want to find a hosting provider. Start here for more info: https://apex.oracle.com/en/platform/deployment/

Comment: Thanks jeffrey. It worked for me.